# Как правильно писать и употреблять: "коий" или "кой"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы, устаревшие-слова

Есть  такой синоним слова "который": "кое", "кои", "коя". Но вот вариант этого слова в мужском роде в письменной речи мне не встречался. Как правильно? "Коий/коему/коим/коимым"?

**Добавил:** Уважаемые участники, я не знаю, чей ответ принимать. И Jasmin, и М_Г, привели примеры, подтверждающие их точки зрения. Я же спросил именно потому, что не знаю, как правильно. Кто-то расставит точки над "i"? Может, допустимо вариативное употребление?

Answer (score 2):

> Меня интересует момент, когда "который" можно заменить на "коий" в таких предложениях: "Это тот человек, который".

Нужно заменить на *кой*.  Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Не потаю от тебя: доподлинно видел человека, **кой** называет себя Петром Федорычем. [В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. Книга первая. Ч. 3 (1934-1939)]
>
> А великан ему шелепугой путь заломил и возговорил тако: «Вода моя от смерти пасет, едино лишь пить ее тому человеку, **кой** мозоли на руках имет. [А. П. Чапыгин. Гулящие люди (1937)]
>
> И вот болит ежедень мое сердце: живу, хожу, почет мне великий, а человеку, **кой** мой почет и жизнь спас, глаз на глаз спасибо сказать не можно… [А. П. Чапыгин. Разин Степан (1927)]
>
> Чрез сие он надеется удовольствовати всех читателей, показывая себя таким доброхотным человеком, **кой** более печется о поступках и делах ближнего, нежели о своих собственных. [Н. И. Новиков. [Полемика с Екатериной II] (1769)]
>
> [текст по-гречески], то есть человек, **кой** никакого дела не имеет, праздный, тунеядец, ни к чему годный, неключимый. [В. К. Тредиаковский. Рассуждение о комедии вообще (1750)]

Comment: Примеры из старых текстов. Может быть, этот вариант  в значении "который" устарел?

Comment: @Jasmin Современные авторы пишут КОИЙ, а современые словари, однако, дают КОЙ. Мне не удалось найти КОИЙ в словарях.  У меня когнитивный диссонанс :)

Comment: Из Интернета (народ тоже в сомнениях): Тупой вопрос: а слово "коий" (в смысле "который") когда-нибудь существовало в языке, хоть русском, хоть церковнославянском, или это такая народная реконструкция от косвенных форм слова "кой" ("коему", "коей" и т. п.)? Стал смотреть в сети - единичные случаи употребления в XIX веке - а потом зато в XX веке и Шолохов, и Пильняк, и пошло, и пошло...

Вот мне тоже захотелось было "коий" написать, а потом сомнение взяло. https://azangru.livejournal.com/381612.html

Answer (score 1):

Правильно **кой**. Приведу статью из словаря Кузнецова:

> **КОЙ**, коего, м.; **КОЯ**, (устар.) **КАЯ**, коей, ж.; **КОЕ**, коего, ср. мн.: **кои**, > коих, коим. 
>   I. местоим. сущ. Нар.-разг. Какой? который? *А кой тебе
>   годик? - Шестой миновал* (Некрасов). 
>   II. союзн. сл. Устар. 1. ед. им. и
>   вин. нет (в придат. определит. предл.). =Который. *В книге описываются
>   только те события, коим автор был свидетель.* 2. (в придат. предл.
>   дополнит.). Который. *В конце концов обнаружили, в коем месте был
>   тайник.* 
> ◊ Кой чёрт. Бранно. Употр. для выражения несогласия с чем-л.,
>   сильного неудовольствия, раздражения по поводу чего-л. *На кой чёрт*
>   (дьявол, леший и т.п.)!; на кой! Разг.-сниж. Зачем, к чему, для чего.
>   
> *В кои веки*, в зн. нареч. Очень редко. *Ни в коей мере*, в зн. нареч.
>   Книжн. Нисколько. *Ни в коем случае*, в зн. нареч. Никогда, ни за что.

Comment: Меня интересует момент, когда "который" можно заменить на "коий" в таких предложениях: "Это тот человек, который". Как правильно? "Это тот человек, коий уже приходил" или "Тот человек, кой уже приходил". Я нигде не нашёл примера употребления.

Comment: Правильно писать - "который". Другие варианты - архаизмы или букинизмы. Понимать их полезно, использовать - не нужно. "Кой" в современной речи используется в основном с 
 предлогом "на" : на кой .... ?

Answer (score 1):

В современных текстах в большинстве случаев **коий**, хотя в словарях такого слова нет, там только ***кой***.

Слово ***коий*** встречается в Нацкорпусе (12 примеров, в том числе современные).

Пустынника, **коий**, по Писаниям, был облачен в желтого цвета верблюжью власяницу! [Петр Алешковский. Жизнеописание Хорька (**1990-1993**)]

Итак, ...мы, уж не робея, вышли из того покою вон и продолжали стремление свое к привлекательному дивану, находящемуся близь нашего Ивана, т.е. большого брата, **коий** не взирая на Морфея, который, кажется, старался усыпить его, извлекал из шестиструнной гитары меланхолические звуки. [И. И. Лапин. Дневник (**1818)**]

Опоздавшая труженица поливала нас вослед, как ей только хотелось, не жалея того изысканного столичного мата, **коий** будет с годами еще более усовершенствован. [Виктор Астафьев. Веселый солдат (**1987-1997**) // «Новый Мир», 1998]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%EE%E8%E9&p=0

**Размышления на тему**

Вот интересно, откуда взялась форма ***коий*** и какая из форм **логичнее для современного языка?** Может быть, исходя из склонения?

Возьмем **классический пример из орфографии**: (1) птичий ― птичьего, (2) горячий ― горячего. В первом случае ИЙ ― это суффикс (Й сохраняется при склонении, этот звук обозначает разделительный Ь), а во втором окончание ИЙ не сохраняется при склонении.

Если мы имеем ***коего, коему*** (горячего, горячему), то должны иметь начальную форму с окончанием ИЙ ― ***ко/ий***, ко/его, ко/ему. А если начальная форма ***кой***, то тогда кой/его, кой/ему.

Может быть, так ***кой*** превратился в ***коий, *** если это действительно новая форма.

Answer (score 1):

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) пишет:
**кой**
Вопросительное и относительное местоимение.
3. *относ. устар. книжн.* то же, что который; присоединяет придаточные определительные, указывая на тот предмет, о котором говорится в главном предложении.

Примеров именно с "кой" не приводит.
Я нашла вот такие строки у [Деметрия Паскаля](https://books.google.ee/books?id=Qsg7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT279&lpg=PT279&dq=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=tLjeVcXKJs&sig=-qkQwEyFRuNYl9Q7Jul-sLiqvgo&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL0Kyt-fDbAhXBjiwKHeagALUQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&f=false):

*...От благочестия рождается национальная, культурная гордыня,

Возжигается слепой **патриотизм,**

**Кой** изживёт остатнее число ума последков,

Зане не Бог, но правила Его для фарисеев есть святыня.*

*Тот **человек, кой** в религиозности живёт,

Не в Бога,

Отнюдь, верит,

Но только в то, что за блаженность фарисейство рок ему зачтет...*

Такие — у Николая Кондратьева ("Лекарь-воевода"):

*— Что ты болтаешь?! Какой кум?! — перешел также на шепот и Злыдень, присев даже.

— **Тот самый, кой исчез**. Ладно, отворяй.*

Да, действительно, **коий** встречается довольно часто, причем, как мне кажется, его значение больше тяготеет к слову **какой**, а не "который".

*Гой ты, Хмель, от (...) отступись —

К лихому человеку привяжись:

Коий лихо думает,

Коий Правды не любит,

Коий мыслью да делом всех губит!*
(Заговор от чрезмерного хмелепития)

У меня сразу возник вопрос: если слово "коий" — правильное, то как склонять-то его?
Нашлись и [рекомендации](http://www.reright.ru/analysis/936633~%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B9.html), и другие словоформы.
Но я бы все-таки остановилась на том, что на сегодняшний день грамотно писать "кой" (поживем — увидим).

Answer (score 0):

Мне тоже нужно было это слово написать, интернет не помог. Посчитал коий, от кой, будет верно.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).