# Разница между "которым" и "коим"

Tags: выбор-слов

Есть ли разница между "которым" и "коим"?
Например.
Он увидел людей, которым (коим) было трудно позавидовать.
Есть ощущение, что "которым" более книжно-литературное. Так ли?

Comment: Вот тут можно посмотреть: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441601/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9 (Как правильно писать и употреблять: “коий” или “кой”?)

Comment: Разница, например, в корректности предложений: "Которым больным стало лучше?" и "Коим больным стало лучше?". Последнее некорректно на мой взгляд. (Хотя в словарях и пишут о вопросительности местоимения кой, давая экзотические примеры "кой черт тебе он сдался?" и "кой год тебе идет?", но все таки сомневаюсь насчет корректности "Коим больным стало лучше?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ответы на многие вопросы можно найти в толковом словаре, где указаны **стили речи**.

Большой толковый словарь

**КОЙ, коего**, м.; КОЯ, (устар.) КАЯ, коей, ж.; КОЕ, коего, ср. мн.: кои, коих, коим.
I. **местоим. сущ. Нар.-разг.** Какой? который? * А кой тебе годик? - Шестой миновал (Некрасов).

II. **союзн. сл. Устар.** 1. ед. им. и вин. нет (в придат. определит. предл.). = Который. **В книге описываются только те события, коим автор был свидетель**. 2. (в придат. предл. дополнит.). Который. В конце концов обнаружили, в коем месте был тайник.

◊ Кой чёрт. Бранно. Употр. для выражения несогласия с чем-л., сильного неудовольствия, раздражения по поводу чего-л. На кой чёрт (дьявол, леший и т.п.)!; на кой! Разг.-сниж. Зачем, к чему, для чего. <В кои веки, в зн. нареч. Очень редко. Ни в коей мере, в зн. нареч. Книжн. Нисколько. Ни в коем случае, в зн. нареч. Никогда, ни за что.

2. Мы видим, что **КОЙ** – это **разговорный** стиль в значении вопросительного слова в простом предложении, но в значении союзного слова оно **устарело**. Но, как известно, устаревшие слова могут употребляться авторами в **высоком или ироническом** стиле.
3. ***Он увидел людей, которым (коим) было трудно позавидовать.***

Это похоже на книжную речь, поэтому можно предположить, что КОИМ здесь может обозначать высокий стиль. Но это должно быть **ясно из контекста**. Таким образом,  использование устаревшего слова должно быть **обоснованным**, иначе это будет выглядеть как стилистическая неточность.

4. **Вывод**

Местоимение **КОТОРЫЙ** характерно для книжной речи, обычно в разговоре или в художественных текстах мы делаем **замену** (слово кажется «тяжеловесным»).  Например: *Местность, *по которой (где)* протекала река…*  Но в данном случае  такая замена невозможна, поэтому здесь это скорее общий стиль речи (такой вариант предложения может применяться и в научной, и в художественной литературе).

Местоимение **КОЙ** – использование устаревшего слова для обозначения высокого и иронического стиля.

**Примечание**

Что касается ссылки, то там немного другая тема (различение КОЙ и КОИЙ), а вот этот вопрос не кажется решенным. Материалы по теме для обсуждения:

https://azangru.livejournal.com/381612.html

[https://rinabel.livejournal.com/62627.html#:~:text=Местоимения%20"коий"%2C%20во%20всяком%20случае%2C,что%20это%20никакое%20не%20просторечие](https://rinabel.livejournal.com/62627.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%2C,%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5)